# troubleshoot for "if" function

Tags: function, if-statement

When compiling the following segment of code, I am receiving the error, "expected-primary expression before "int". Anyone have an idea what the problem is?

```
void letterGrade (int score)
{
     if (int score >= 90)
     {
             scoreLetter = 'A'
     }
     else if (int score >= 80)
     {
             scoreLetter = 'B'
     }
 }
```

Edit: Code Cleanup

Answer (score 4):

remove "int" in the if statement, the variable is defined already

Answer (score 3):

Remove the int keyword before score in if comparision.

void letterGrade (int score) 
{

if (score >= 90) { scoreLetter = 'A';}

else if (score >= 80) { scoreLetter = 'B';}

}

Comment: int main() { int score; string scoreLetter; char A, B, C, D, F; cout<<"Enter the grade: "; cin>> score; void letterGrade (int score); void gradeFinal (int score); cout<<"The letter grade is "<< scoreLetter<<"."; } void letterGrade (int score) { if (score >= 90) { string scoreLetter = 'A'} else if (score >= 80) { scoreLetter = 'B'} else if (score >= 70) When compiling, I am getting an error for the lince scoreLetter = 'A', etc. What is wrong with this?
Error states 'scoreLetter' undefined. Do I need to define scoreLetter in the function not the main?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you should remove the `int` from in front of score in the test statements is that with the int your code defines new local variables named score within that scope. Whereas you intend to use the score variable for the overall function scope, not just score defined within your if statement.